# Using python pandas script on multiple files

Tags: python, pandas

I have a python (pandas) script that reads csv files into a dataframe, edits them, and makes them into a new csv (output):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r'\filename.csv', sep=',')

# I skipped over the dataframe edits

try:
    df.to_csv(r'outputfilename', sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')    
except IOError as e:
    print('Could not make Excel file' % e)`
```

I would like to use it on multiple csv files at once and get multiple outputs (csv's):

I have tried:

```
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

filename = askopenfilename()

df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=',')
...
```

and it works (gives me an selection window), but I am only able to choose one file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If doing it one after another rather than all files at once is sufficient, have a look at the [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) module:

**1. Create list of files in target directory**

```
target_directory = r'Path/to/your/dir'
file_list = glob.glob(target_directory + "/*.csv") 
# Include slash or it will search in the wrong directory!
```

**2. Loop through files in list and do your magic**

```
for file in file_list:                # Loop files
    df_result = your_function(file)   # Put your logic into a separate function
    new_filename = file.replace('.csv', '_processed.csv')
    df_result.to_csv(new_filename, index = False)
```

Comment: This works for the most part. It goes through the files and edits them, but the last part .to_csv returns: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_csv'`

Comment: I used: `for file in file_list:                # Loop files
        df_result = use_pandas_script(file)   # Put your logic into a separate function
 new_filename = file.replace('.csv', '_processed.csv')
 df_result.to_csv(new_filename, index=False)
 print(df_result.info())` 

and the result was: `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 0 entries
Empty DataFrameNone`

so you're right the dataframe was empty. Is there anything that can fix that?

Comment: this means that your use_pandas_script() returns an empty dataframe. please update your initial QUESTION and include the full use_pandas_script(), beginning with def and ending with return

Comment: I think I see what happened. I forgot to include `return df4` at the end of the function. I have included it and it works so far. Wow thanks! I feel so stupid for missing that.

Comment: I am happy to help - happy coding!

Comment: Thanks @sudonym ! This means a lot to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
filename = askopenfilename()
```

In this code you are saying that 'askopenfilename' that is to open one file, where as you should open multiple files you should try the below code

```
import Tkinter,tkFileDialog
dir = Tkinter.Tk()
mul_file = tkFileDialog.askopenfilenames(parent=dir,title='Choose a 
                                                   multiple file')
```

'mul_file' will be tuple. if required change it to list by

```
mul_file=list(mul_file)
```

this gives all choosed files in a list.iterate list in loop and do your csv manipulation in it